# Bypass Kotlin "Property getter or setter expected"

Tags: android, kotlin

I need to create a private field and use it without access to it from other classes. But i can't instantiate it in a constructor. 
I'm developing for Android, and a problematic field screenWakeLocker can`t be instantiated this way:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
private val screenWakeLocker: PowerManager.WakeLock = 
                            (getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE) as PowerManager)
                            .newWakeLock(PowerManager.FULL_WAKE_LOCK, "")
```

"System services not available to Activities before onCreate()"

So i instantiate it in OnCreate:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
private var game: Game = Game()
private var screenWakeLocker?: PowerManager.WakeLock;

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    screenWakeLocker = (getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE) as PowerManager).newWakeLock(PowerManager.FULL_WAKE_LOCK, "")
}

override fun onResume(){
    super.onResume()
    screenWakeLocker.acquire()
}
```

and get a compilation error "Property getter or setter expected" at ?: PowerManager.WakeLock

How to make it unavailable to other classes and to use it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two options:

1. option one, if you want to use "var" you can add **lateinit**
2. option two, you can use **by lazy**, where objects are initialised when it is needed

   ```
   private lateinit var screenWakeLocker: PowerManager.WakeLock
   private val screenWakeLockerTwo by lazy {(getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE) as PowerManager).newWakeLock(PowerManager.FULL_WAKE_LOCK, "")}

   override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
       setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
       screenWakeLocker = (getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE) as PowerManager).newWakeLock(PowerManager.FULL_WAKE_LOCK, "")
   }`
   ```

I think option two is better.

Answer (score -1):

Use lateinit keyword for lazy initialization.

private lateinit var screenWakeLocker: PowerManager.WakeLock